# Bibliography won't compile in Winedt 9.0

Tags: bibtex, winedt

I recently purchased a new computer and reinstalled Miktex 2.9, with WinEdt 9.0.  By and large everything works until I tried to compile a document with a bibliography and nothing happened.  I tried to compile the same document with TexWorks, and it worked beautifully, hence a problem (I suspect) with WinEdt 9.0.
My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\title{XXXX}
\author{Joe Bloggs}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is anyone able to suggest what may be happening?
WinEdt gives me this message when I try to BibTex the file:

[image]

The .bib file is:

```
@Book{Overbye1991,
Title                    = {Lonely Hearts of the Cosmos},
Author                   = {Dennis Overbye},
Publisher                = {MacMillan},
Year                     = {1991},
Address                  = {London},
Timestamp                = {2015.05.11}}
```

Thank you for your help!

The log had this to say:
[image]

Comment: if bibtex started at all it would have left a log file `.blg` which will have some information.

Comment: You must change the configuration so that winedt call biber instead of bibtex. You can also install http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/LaTeXify.php to get biber menu entry.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154755#154755

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was that the OP was running bibtex instead of biber.